# What would be the regular expression for this in java?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am using Java.util.Scanner to read a file and have to find the pairs like :

SET key value

have to skip the comments starting with #,
have to skip blank lines,
it is a txt file: only has comments , blank lines and lines containing values in format : SET key value.
keys donot have spaces, values can be in "".

I am facing trouble with what regular expression to use to skip lines and comments, or if I can directly use find pattern in Scanner to find key value pairs. I am not good at regular expressions, so please help.
Or if there is a better way to do this other than scanner please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to put it all into on RE, use multiple steps.
Assume you have the line as a `String`:

1. trim it to remove leading and trailing Whitespace.
2. if `line.length() == 0` or `line.matches("#.*")` skip it.
3. Use `line.substring( 5, line.length() )` to remove the leading 4 characters, for safety, you can check if they equal "SET ".
4. Use `line.indexof("\\s")` to find the 1st space, that's where you have to split.
5. Use `line.substring(...)` to get the key and the value.

Comment: Thanks, how do I find if a line starts with #? line.matches("#") doesnt work.

Comment: @MagicBeans: Sorry, my mistake, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```
SET (\w*) ("?)(.*)\2
```

It will only match the lines that you wanted and allows you to directly extract the string for 'key' as the first capture group and the string for 'value' (without the quotes) as the third capture group. It will also extract everything between the quotes for 'value' (if there are quotes) and everything to the end of the line if there are none.

As a string in Java code it should look like this:

```
"SET (\\w*) (\"?)(.*)\\2"
```

Comment: how do I escape " in the expression ?

Comment: @MagicBeans A single backslash before the quote should be enough in Java. That just tells it to not end the string there. In the end, your complete regex string would look like this: `"SET (\w*) (\"?)(.*)\2"`

Comment: @KMoschcau: When your regex is a string constant defined in code, of course you need to escape the backslashes too: `"SET (\\w*) (\\"?)(.*)\\2"`

Comment: this doesnot work gives : Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @MagicBeans see Frank Puffer's comment. You need to escape the backslashes as well. Don't escape the backslash that already escapes the quote though. I will update my original answer accordingly.

Comment: @FrankPuffer You should not escape the backslash that already escapes the quote though.